# Magento2 - How to move checkout page side bar Cart Items section below the shipping method on checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods, cart-items

Kindly help me in this

Magento2 - How to move checkout page side bar Cart Items section below the shipping method on checkout page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add .opc-sidebar {width:100%; float: left;} and .opc-wrapper {width:100%;} to your css this will work. Add the above css under min-width: 769px

Comment: Thanks for your response sukumar but i need with xml not with css because I need to move only cart Items section to below shipping method remains the same